# How do I reshape the images from a npy file with Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have '.npy' image dataset file(which contain RGB value of each pixel of each picture as numpy array).
It's shape is (256,256,3) and I want to reshape it to (96,96,3)

(it means I have 256 by 256 pixel picture in RGB and I want 96 by 96 pictures)

(it's obvious I can't use `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` function.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just `tf.image.resize`?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

arr = np.random.randint(0, 256, (100, 256, 256, 3))

with open('test.npy', 'wb') as f:
    np.save(f, arr)

with open('test.npy', 'rb') as f:
    a = np.load(f)

resize = lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, (96, 96))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a).map(resize).batch(1)

print(next(iter(ds)).shape)
```

```
(1, 96, 96, 3)
```

Comment: thanks it works. but how do I use this with 'train_on_batch' function?

Comment: I don't know. You mentioned Tensorflow so I suggested a Tensorflow approach.

Comment: I mean what it returns? numpy array or Tensor or ..

Comment: it returns a `tf.data.Dataset` object, which you can pass directly to `model.fit`, or anything else

Comment: can I use indexing with it?

Comment: if you want to play with it, you could just use `tf.image.resize(a, (96, 96)).numpy()`. but if you're using Tensorflow you should eventually get to know `tf.data.Dataset`